# Monitor MySQL Databases and Notify Updates

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an application, which was not developed by me, so I cannot change the source code, but I have access to its database. I want to monitor changes in certain tables in real-time, to notify another application that is being developed by me in NodeJs, when changes occur in these tables.

The moment an insertion occurs, for example, I need an alert to be issued. I've already researched some things, but I haven't found anything that really suits them. What could I do in this case?

Comment: Take a backup every day and compare todays' to  yesterdays' backup. You won't be able to establish whodunit but maybe you don't need to. You could improve your question by stating the what your requirement is for monitoring changes..

Comment: I need to monitor in real-time, when an insertion happens, for example, I need to be notified immediately

Comment: Add a CDC connector to your database and then listen to the events it produces. It will not be easy though it will work exactly as you need: https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/mysql-cdc-with-apache-kafka-and-debezium-3d45c00762e4

Answer (score 0):

There is a free open source Java program called "Mysql Monitor Tool" which can monitor a MySQL (or multiple) databases in real time:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlmt/

or

I use JET Profiler: http://www.jetprofiler.com/

it has a free version too.

or

just either read out the transaction log every x seconds or just make your own logging where you insert every new thing in a table (with a start and end time). Then you could do a 'select top 50' of that table and refresh every x seconds via Ajax. It's not a perfect technique but it's just doing a top 50 select statement on your SQL server, which isn't that time/memory consuming

or read this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63685/168620